# Attempting to move out of a copy-on-write existential

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode9, copy-on-write

I am getting this new runtime error when I am trying to pass around a dictionary as param to a method defined in a subclass.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
  cell.configure(self.data[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) // FAILS HERE STATING: "Attempting to move out of a copy-on-write existential"

  ...
  ...
}
```

This used to run perfectly fine on Swift 2.3

How do I fix this issue?

PS: I am running Xcode 9.0(9A235) (which is using Swift 3.2) on Mac 10.12.6

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using `[String: Any]` instead of `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, and it started working. Weird issue with Dictionary Type Casting.